# Deleting all archives off a flash drive

Tags: arrays, bash, flash, archive

Have written a BASH script to find/delete all archives off an inserted flash drive.

Need feedback on my code.  Hoping it is correct as written:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Author:       Nyle Davis          Created 14-06-12
# Purpose:      Empty the inserted flash of any/all .tar type backup files.
# File:         clean-drives.sh

function findtar {
    BDRV=$1;                                                        # If target dir not passed then
    if [ -z ${BDRV} ]; then                             # hardcode to last known good
        BDRV="/mnt/flash/64Gig";                        # mount point.
    fi
    CWD=$(pwd);
    cd ${BDRV};
    # Capture in array all compression file extensions
    compray=(a, afa, apk, ar, ark, bz2, bzip2, cfs, dar, gz, gzip, iso, jar. kgb, 
                lz, lzma, lzo, rz, mar, pak6, pak7, pak8, par, par2, pea, rar, rk, 
                shar, tar, tbz2, tgz, tlz, xz, yzl, z, zip, zipx, zoo, zpak, zz, 7z);
    for i in ${compray[@]}; do
        for n in $(find . -name "*.${i}" ) ; do #find & delete archive files
            rm -f ${n};
        done;       # end: for n in $find 
    done;           # end: for i in $compray
    cd ${CWD};
}

findtar;

exit 0;
```

Comment: Arrays in bash are not comma separated, but whitespace separated. Your files probably don't have extensions like `rar,`.

Comment: Code reviews belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. In any case, running it through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) is a good first step.

Comment: rather than running find again and again for each new file extension, i'd  find -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" ...  to gather them all in one run.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Correcting my code

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified like this:

```
function findtar {
    local BDRV=${1:-"/mnt/flash/64Gig"} IFS='|'
    local compray=(a afa apk ar ark bz2 bzip2 cfs dar gz gzip iso jar kgb 
                lz lzma lzo rz mar pak6 pak7 pak8 par par2 pea rar rk 
                shar tar tbz2 tgz tlz xz yzl z zip zipx zoo zpak zz 7z)

    find "$BDRV" -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[.](${compray[*]})$" ## -delete
}

findtar
```

I commented out `-delete`. If you want to delete files you'd just need to add it. Test the code first before you do.

Other forms:

```
find "$BDRV" -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[.](${compray[*]})$" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f --

find "$BDRV" -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[.](${compray[*]})$" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do
    rm -f -- "$REPLY"
done

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do
    rm -f -- "$REPLY"
done < <(exec find "$BDRV" -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[.](${compray[*]})$" -print0)

readarray -t FILES < <(exec find "$BDRV" -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[.](${compray[*]})$)" && \
    rm -f -- "${FILES[@]}"
```

Comment: Do I still need the "cd" to get to working dir?  Also think I missed a call to the script dir which will always be on the flash, something like: "/mnt/flash/64Gig/Scripts/Backups"  Always need scripts executing from the flash and .tar.gz creation on the flash!

Comment: The delete command would be like:  rm -f < find "$BDRV" -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[.](${compray[*]})"  Am I right?

Comment: I find it unnecessary to change directory actually.

Comment: konsolebox,  OK never saw the "local" thing before.  Also on your 1st example, how do I get it to echo for testing?  Don't even think it is finding the drive.  Cheers!

Comment: @OldManRiver If you refer to the real first example, just don't add `-delete` yet. As for the first example in the other set of forms, just insert `echo` in the `xargs` command: `... | xargs -0 echo rm -f --`

Comment: Trying all the forms and adding "echo" to make sure before actually letting the "delete" loose!